# OpenGL ES 1.x programmable pipeline

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

Is it possible to have programmable shaders in OpenGL ES 1.x ? 
My guess is no from looking at the API, however I would like to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [specs, e.g. OpenGL ES 2.0.25](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf). At the end, a short summary lists the differences to former versions. From this spec:

> It introduces programmable vertex and fragment shaders, but removes
>   the corresponding fixed-function pipeline functionality.

*Skating on thin ice:* Before assimilation into the spec, these were *extensions*; e.g. the [vertex shader extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/vertex_shader.txt) is written against OpenGL 1.2.1, and OpenGL ES 1.1 is based on OpenGL 1.5. So there could be an extension allowing you programmable shading on OpenGL ES 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you must look in the spec of the device you are coding to.
For instance PS3 has support for OpenGL ES 1.0, but gives a lot of extensions so that you can use CG shaders.